# Contiguous Memory Allocation in C and Memory Access Latency

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, memory-management

I am reading this paper.
http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece447/s13/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=moscibroda.pdf

In it, the current method of memory access used for most architectures with multiple cores is discussed. The paper provides examples of the limitations of the current method when dealing with concurrent threads where on is accessing memory in sequential instructions that is contiguous and the other discontinuous memory locations in sequential instructions.

According to the paper threads that are accessing contiguous memory in sequential instructions will be serviced first by the memory controller. I certainly do not doubt this but the author provides two codes to illustrate an application where contiguous memory is being accessed sequentially and one where contiguous memory is not being accessed sequentially. Here are the codes.

Contiguous memory access

```
// initialize arrays a, b
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    a[index[j]] = b[index[j]];
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    index[j] = j; // streaming index
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        b[index[j]] = scalar * a[index[j]];
```

Non-contiguous memory access

```
// initialize arrays a, b
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
   index[j] = rand(); // random # in [0,N]
 for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    a[index[j]] = b[index[j]];
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
  b[index[j]] = scalar * a[index[j]];
```

My question is if you were to implement this code in C and compile it for x86 or ARM, then run it on some operating system, say Linux, would you have any guarantee that the memory locations of the original buffers you are allocating are physically contiguous? Would they not be only virtual contiguous memory (unless a Linux method like kmalloc() was used)?

*Note: The author specifies that the code provided is pseudo-code, so perhaps my quandary with implementation is unfounded.

Comment: What are "the original buffers", in your opinion? Do you mean the declared arrays `a`, `b`, and `index`?

Comment: You may be reading more into the code than is there. The code is not pseudo code, it is actual C. The key to the contiguous guarantee is that *arrays* are used. Arrays (as opposed to *pointer to pointer to type*) guarantee sequential memory locations for all elements. In the Contiguous memory access code, you are simply iterating over the contiguous elements *in-order*, where as the non-contiguous example iterates over random indexes in the array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. are they? they certainly are contiguous in virtual memory, because I can use C iterator operations to iterate over the locations in virtual memory using a pointer. Does this also hold true for the physical values of the virtual memory location in the memory? IE when I create an array, does the compiler choose a set of locations in the virtual memory map whose physical locations are contiguous?

Comment: @JackFrye Even if the pages were not contiguous, there are `PAGE_SIZE` bytes on each page that *are*, and that is where it matters.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that would mean his code is only pseudo-code and the implementation would rely completely on the OS. He mentions he performed a test on Windows XP. What you are describing is the GNU Linux API. This code can't be used generically for any N. It must be pseudocode. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if you were to implement this code in C and compile it
>   for x86 or ARM, then run it on some operating system, say Linux, would
>   you have any guarantee that the memory locations of the original
>   buffers you are allocating are physically contiguous?

Answer: **yes**

The code is not pseudo code, it is actual C (missing only `% N`, the modulo operator, required to limit the return of `rand()` from `0-(N-1)`). The key to the contiguous guarantee is that *arrays* are used. Arrays in C (as opposed to *pointer to pointer to type*). That guarantee sequential memory locations for all elements in virtual memory (which is normally the only kind of memory handed out by modern memory managers).

In the Contiguous memory access code, you are simply iterating over the contiguous elements *in-order*, where as the non-contiguous example iterates over random indexes in the array.

Your quandary is not unfounded, as there are many instances where collections of objects do not guarantee adjacent elements will be sequential in memory, but the author specified the use of *arrays* in the example which guarantee all elements are sequential (by definition).

Access in the non-contiguous example is made non-contiguous by the use of `rand()` (which is pseudo in the since it is missing the `% N`, but not in syntax) (e.g. `index[j] = rand() % N;` would limit the assignment to `0-N`, but not guarantee all indexes were covered) From my read the intent of the example was to emphasize the direct sequential access within a contiguous block and the non-contiguous example was simply provided as a contra-example where the author illustrates randomly accessing different elements within a sequential block.

Comment: "That guarantee sequential memory locations for all elements in virtual memory" -- yes, but when trying to optimize your program for best performance with respect to memory-latency, is it virtual-address-space-continuity that is important, or physical-address-space-continuity?  Given that (AFAIK) RAM modules don't have any knowledge about OS-level constructs like the page tables, I suspect it's the latter.

Comment: It would take a doctorate level dissertation to frame an answer to that fully (which I don't claim to have in hardware or memory managers, law yes) I suspect that it is the former that is the critical aspect. If (and I say if), memory managers were smart enough to bundle together non-continuous portions of physical-address-space and provide that to a program as a contiguous virtual-address block, I don't think the program would have any way to know or care. That is my suspicion, no more, no less.

Comment: Yeah @DavidC.Rankin I think there is a hardware aspect we are missing here that is hard to talk to because it varies by OS and hardware architecture. Much to @JeremyFriesner’s point, I think the concern is how the virtual address space maps to the physical RAM locations. The author was concerned with the pattern of physical memory access of the hardware. My concern was that the first C code he wrote did not guarantee that continuous virtual memory access would correspond to continuous physical memory access by the RAM controller

Comment: Yes, I see the issue, I'm just not sure there is a generic answer to it based on exactly what you address. The machine principles, Harvard and Von Neumann architectures, haven't changed, but the combinations in how they are used and the caches scattered about along the address and data buses have. I think the precise answer to your question whether there is a "*guarantee that continuous virtual memory access would correspond to continuous physical memory access by the RAM controller*" would have to depend on the controller implementation. That is almost voodoo to me`:)`